# Determine matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear function $f:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3 $. It is given that $f\circ f = 0$ and $f(e_1) = e_2 +e_3$ (where $e_i$ denote the canonical basis vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ ). I am to show that  $imf$ is a subspace of $kerf$ and subsequently determine the rank. In additon I have to give an example of a matrix representing $f$.

The first part I think I can show:

$$f\circ f(e_1) = 0 = f(e_2 + e_3)$$

Since $e_2 + e_3$ is the image of $f$ and $f(e_2 + e_3) = 0$, the image must be a subspace of the kernel.

I am not entirely sure  how to proceed from here. My argument would have been that because $imf$ is a subspace of $kerf$ then the rank is one. My matrix would then have the form:

$$ f = \begin{pmatrix}0 & a_1 & b_1 \\ 1 & a_2 & b_2 \\ 1 & a_3 & b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The vector $e_2+e_3$ is an *element* of the image, but surely not the image of $f$. To prove $Im f\subset Ker f$, you need to show that $f(y)=0$ whenever $y$ can be written as $y=f(x)$, for some $x$.

Comment: So, couldn't I show that in a similar way: $f(x) = y$ then $f \circ f(x) = f(y)$ and this is equal to zero from the definition of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in im f$, then $f(x)=y$ for some $x \in \mathbb R^3.$ It follows that $f(y)=f(f(x))=0$, hence $y\in ker f.$

Furthermore we have $3= \dim ker f +\dim im f \le 2 \dim ker f.$

This gives $ \dim ker f \ge 3/2$, hence $ \dim f \ge 2.$

Hence $ \dim imf \le 1.$

Since $e_2+e_3 \in im f$, we get  $ \dim imf = 1.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible then to construct a uniquely defined matrix representing $f$ ?